# Styling react navbar

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using the react-site-nav package in a react application with typescript. I am having trouble styling the navbar. The default colour is black and I am not being able to change it.
[link to navbar package] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-site-nav)

I have to style the 'Site Nav' element provided by the package.

```
<SiteNav>
        <ContentGroup title="About" height="200">
         Some text 1
        </ContentGroup>
        <ContentGroup title="Contact" height="200">
         Some text 2
        </ContentGroup>
</SiteNav>
```

I tried using inline styles like this `<SiteNav style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>` but it didn't work. I also tried making a CSS class and other techniques but none worked.

Any help would be appreciated to make the navbar transparent. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the dev tools inspector to see what's going on?

Comment: @AndyHoffman Thanks I took a look at that. There seems to be a CSS style class that comes from the package that sets the colour too. I wasn't able to locate where that stylesheet was in the package so I could customise it. However, I found the answer thanks to the answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library exposes a prop on SiteNav called background

```js
<SiteNav background='transparent'>
```

Here is one of their [examples on their github repo](https://github.com/yusinto/react-site-nav/blob/d93cc53f02f78b5682c233918c04f75d8b727ee1/examples/advanced/src/universal/app/app.js) that includes setting a transparent background